# AutoreleaseFreedObject Issue

Tags: iphone, xcode4, nsautoreleasepool

The Application Window loads the first time giving this warning:

`*** __NSAutoreleaseFreedObject(): release of previously deallocated object (0x583e880) ignored`

The second time the app crashes giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
Where am I wrong?

P.S. I tried to enable Zombies but it gives the same error...

Comment: At which part of code is it raising the error?

Comment: exactly in main.m: int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}      on int retVal line it gives the EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've over released an object.

You may have called `release` on an object that you don't own that is then released when the pool is drained.

Comment: The strange thing is that whilst it runs on Xcode 3 without any crash it returns this error on Xcode 4. I'll give it a try. thanks

Comment: I checked every release but everything is correct. Indeed, I don't understand why the code is running smoother on Xcode 3 but not on Xcode 4. Any other suggestion?